# How do I add MonoBehavoir to sprite (Player)?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I am watching a brackeys video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwcT-Dch0bA&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR6TFcFuzI2bB7TMNIIBpKMQ&index=2)
And the script he used wouldn't work(https://github.com/Brackeys/2D-Character-Controller)
The error is:

```
Can't add script CallBackExcuter! Needs to derive from MonoBehavoir
```

Comment: What have you named the script as? Also, could you show us the code or you downloaded his script?

Comment: I downloaded the script and when I imported it into the name was Movement control

Comment: The Script file name and the class name should be the same

Comment: ok i will try it

Answer (score 3):

The script name in unity and file name has to be the same!
Yay!

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably occurs because the name of the script and the name of the class you have need to be the same, Example:
The script name: "Yeet",
The class name: "Yeet". 
Try renaming the class/script.